# request.getAttribute is null in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am setting the request.getAttribute as below in my jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%


        request.setAttribute("name", "anita");


        %>
        <%=request.getAttribute("name") %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="QnAAuthServlet">

    <input type="hidden" name="orgName" value="SENDFORBOB"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am able to print it also in my JSP

I am trying to request.getAttribute in my servlet as below

```
    public class QnAAuthServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public QnAAuthServlet() {
            super();

        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        enter code here
            String name = (String) request.getAttribute("name");
            System.out.println("name = " + name);

        }

    }
```

But name is always null in my servlet. Please someone help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

A request represents... an HTTP request. As soon as the server has finished generating the response for the request, the request doesn't exist anymore. When your servlet is executed, it getsa new HttpServletRequest object, and of course the attributes that the JSP stored in the previous request are forgotten for long.

If you want to pass data from an HTML page (generated by a JSP) to a servlet, it has to be passed as a request parameter, or sent as a form input.

Comment: But, how do i send an object to the servlet from JSP? Not just a string. This object has internal getters to get the values in it.

Comment: There are several possibilities. 1. Don't pass objects at all. Save data to the database, and retrieve it later. 2. Use several hidden fields 3. Use the session, ... Without a concrete problem to solve, it's hard to provide a good answer.

Comment: Ok. I tried this as well. But session.getAttribute("name"); works on non IE browsers. But, not on IE. I have set the level of accepting cookies in IE to low to make it work. Why does this happen? And can you please let me know as can i use urlrewriting in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are sending a new request to the servlet. Request parameters live as long as request is done and are not available when response is served.

If you want to pass the name, you will have to do something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="someValue">
```

If you want parameters to be available for multiple requests, then you can use `HttpSession` for that.

```
session.setAttribute("name","prasad");
```

Comment: Ok. I tried this as well. But session.getAttribute("name"); works on non IE browsers. But, not on IE. I have set the level of accepting cookies in IE to low to make it work.

Comment: I need a small clarification, when i do request.setAttribute in servlet and try to get the request.getAttribute in forwarded jsp..i will get value. How does that work? Internally a jsp is also a servlet. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you servlet is getting a new request.  if you need to pass name to the servlet in the request, then you'll need to create an input element with the name "name".  You can't set the request that will be posted in the request that is rendering the current page.

Comment: Currently in this example i have passed only String. But, in my actual implementation, i have to pass an object from jsp to servlet. So, if i create input element, that will not help me.

Comment: Unless you are using spring or something to map your request in as an object you are not going to be able to have an object in your request.

Comment: It's probably not recommended, but you could place an object in the session.  I don't see any reason why you'd be placing a value in the request in the JSP to have it come back in the request anyway since that is already being rendered server side.

Comment: Ok. I tried this as well. But session.getAttribute("name"); works on non IE browsers. But, not on IE. I have set the level of accepting cookies in IE to low to make it work. Why does this happen? And can you please let me know as can i use urlrewriting in this case?

Comment: the session is maintained server side and is not affected by a users browser.  maybe you should look into that again.

Comment: That is true. But IE is rejecting the cookies, which i set. If i make the level of blocking cookies to low in privacy settings. It works.

Comment: that sounds like another issue.  and i'm not sure.  I would try a jquery plugin to simplify creating cookies.  something like: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/